# How can i use string paramater into addmarker?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to use an image into paramater. There is a problem but i dont know where. Can some one help me.

This is my div part; In this part i am not sure it will be placeholder or another else. in that box it will be string.

```
<div id="floating-panel">
<input id="latlng" type="text" value="38.96374,35.2433">
<input id="img1" type="text" placeholder="Put your picture name">
<input id="submit" type="button" value="Bul">
</div>
```

This is my addMarker function.

```
function addMarker(location, map, img) {
        var markers = [];
        var image = img + '.png';
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: location,
             map: map,
             icon: image
          });
          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'rightclick', function(event) {
          marker.setMap(null);
         });
          markers.push(marker);
        }
```

I will call function in here.

I am not sure where should i use that or is it syntactically correct. 
var imagebox = document.getElementById('img1');

```
function geocodeLatLng(geocoder, map, infowindow) 
        {
          var input = document.getElementById('latlng').value;
          var latlngStr = input.split(',', 2);
          var latlng = {lat: parseFloat(latlngStr[0]), lng: parseFloat(latlngStr[1])};
          geocoder.geocode({'location': latlng}, function(results, status) 
          {
            if (status === 'OK') 
            {
              if (results[1]) 
              {
                var imagebox = document.getElementById('img1');
                map.setZoom(7);
                map.setCenter(latlng);
                addMarker(latlng, map, imagebox);
                infowindow.setContent(results[1].formatted_address);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
              } 
              else 
              {
                window.alert('No results found');
              }
            } 
            else 
            {
              window.alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
            }
          });
        }
```

Comment: `imagebox` is an object of your `<input>` tag. You should actually send `imagebox.value` as parameter.

Comment: thank you for that. That worked. i spent 2 hours for that really appreciate

Comment: No problem, mate.

Answer (score 0):

You're sending an `<input>` tag as parameter, instead of a `string`.

See the example below:

```js
function sendValue() {
  var i = document.getElementById('img1');
  console.log(i);
  
  var i = document.getElementById('img1').value;
  console.log(i);
}
```

```html
<input id="img1" type="text" placeholder="Put your picture name">
<input type="button" value="Send" onclick="sendValue()">
```